# Sort array with multiple values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you sort an array like this `fullnamearray.push(firstname +" "+ lastname);`?I want to sort it by lastname not firstname. The list should be displayed firstname followed by lastname.

code

```
 fullnamearray.push(firstname +" "+ lastname);
 fullnamearray.sort();
  for(var i = 0; i < fullnamearray.length; i++){
               Name.innerHTML += '<li>' + fullnamearray[i] + '</li>';
               }
```

Comment: please post the content of fullnamearray array

Comment: Don't build the array like that, then. Maybe `namearray.push({first: firstname, last: lastName})`. Or `push([firstname, lastname])`. That way, you can sort it without splitting the string again (which may not even work for people like "Norma Jean Baker")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate them when you output, not when you store:

```
fullnamearray.push([lastname, firstname]);
fullnamearray.sort();
for(var i = 0; i < fullnamearray.length; i++){
     Name.innerHTML += '<li>' + fullnamearray[i][1] + " " +  fullnamearray[i][0] + '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Does `sort` work on array-type elements like that without a comparator function?

Comment: @Thilo: yes, because the default comparator is `x.toString() <> y.toString()` and `toString` is well defined for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> ?I want to sort it by lastname not firstname. The list should be
>   displayed firstname followed by lastname.

```
fullnamearray.sort( function(a,b){
  var lastNameA = a.split(" ")[1];
  var lastNameB = b.split(" ")[1];
  return lastNameA.localeCompare( lastNameB );
})
```

Now you can display the list in the same manner you were doing earlier.

Above method will fail if `firstname` or `lastname` has a space character in between, so maybe you can follow what @Thilo has suggested

```
fullnamearray.push({first: firstname, last: lastName});
fullnamearray.sort( function(a,b){
  var lastNameA = a.lastName;
  var lastNameB = b.lastName;
  return lastNameA.localeCompare( lastNameB );
});
```

and display list as

```
for(var i = 0; i < fullnamearray.length; i++){
    Name.innerHTML += '<li>' + fullnamearray[i].firstName + " " + fullnamearray[i].lastName '</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fullnamearray.push(firstname +" "+ lastname);
fullnamearray.sort(function (name1, name2) {
    return name1.split(' ')[1] > name1.split(' ')[1];
});
```